# Setting height of web page automatically

Tags: css, html, dom

I am working on a `web-application`, there are many static page and dynamic pages as well. So I want to set their height as per the content. 
To do this is I have simply created an outer div where I have given styles related to container only. This is as following

```
.mainbox
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%; 
}
```

and in the next selector I have specified a fixed height that helps me to extend the background area upto the content of my home page. But that doesn't solve my purpose. It is as following.

```
.mbstyles
{
    margin-top:0; height:800px; background-color:#FCFAE6 
}
```

Now when I browse other static/dynamic web-pages as per the content either there is much empty back ground space or all space have consumed. Please suggest what more should I do to manage this height according to the content.

Thanks!!

Comment: doesnt' height:auto work?

Comment: not the best way but you can use overflow:hidden

Comment: you may use `min-height:800px;`

Comment: may I know how it will help me to maintain height, I mean if there is any difference in height and min-height.. thanks !

Comment: Min-height:800px; means that the div will be at least 800px, and if the content is longer, it will naturally expand past 800px and wrap around all the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using floating divs? If so, remove the height:800px; and try adding the following to the end of the container:

```
<div class="mainbox">
    // all of your content

    //important new part:
    <div class="breaker"></div>
</div>
```

And to your css add:

```
div.breaker
{
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
```

Floating content does not contribute to the height of their parent element (for some reason).
The `clear:both` instruction in the breaker makes sure that the div is rendered after all the floating content, and it does not take part in the "float-flow", so to say, and even breaks the float-flow in such a way that floated divs after the breaker are in a new chain that is displayed after/under the breaker.
Because the breaker is displayed under the floating divs, but is not a floating div itself, the container needs to stretch to fit its content, which is what we want!

I hope this helps!